# Delivery method is not visible in the Magento 2 api

Tags: magento2, rest-api, webapi

I have already created a delivery and payment module and they are automatically exposed in the Magento 2 api rest, but a third shipping method does not appear, despite being working normally on the backend and frontend.
How to make the module exposed?
[image]

[image: Este metodo não renorna via api rest, veja o json de retorno na figura acima]

Comment: please share your api calling data, screenshots may be. Sometimes there are few things which are necessary to fetch shipping, may be you missed some of these

Comment: I'm using swagger to verify and I receive all 5 methods, except the motoboym2 module. "http://photocolor.br/rest/all/V1/carts/20889/shipping-methods"

Comment: You havn't used any post variables here?

Comment: I didn't understand, post variable?

Comment: Yes, the parameters are correct, I send the request using Java to the URL [https://example.com/rest/store_id/V1/cart_id/mine/estimate-shipping-methods/] with token and I get the json containing the 5 methods but there are 6, missing 1. The frontend shows the 6 methods.

Comment: Not just token, you need to pass address also, please check my answer, you will understand

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can get shipping methods using APIs

one is when your address is saved, then use address id in post

> **Get Shipping methods (By address ID):** [POST] 
>  URL: exampl.com/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id?addressId=968

2nd is when you don't have any saved address, then use full address in post variable

> **Get Shipping methods (By address):** [POST]
>  URL: example.com/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods?address[city]=San+Jose&address[street][0]=ABC+Street&address[street][1]=Near+Park&address[country_id]=US&address[postcode]=95116

This way you will get all available shipping methods.

Comment: understand, I'm passing all parameters correctly including the address and the call to estimate-shipping-methods returns json with all methods except 1. See the figure in the question, the method is available on the frontend. It is not a problem in the post, simply the method is not available via rest api.